# Using the Lumix GM-1 for Aurora

Tags: night, panasonic-lumix, aurora-borealis

is it possible to use the GM-1 with the standard 12-32mm lens for night photography and the Aurora? My attempts so far have been null. The manual doesnt say much. Is there general settings to use for night time?

Comment: Honestly, just using the built in modes so far. I have no idea where to start with manual adjustments. It's been years since i've done it at uni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible?

It should be. The GM1 is a m4/3  and while that's not large it's a lot better than what's in a compact or a phone.

A quick search om Flickr turned up [this one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/flickrtimelesslee1/12956333645). 
The settings say F3.2, 30sec and ISO 800. You should be able to match that.

The standard recipe would be:

- use a tripod
- enable saving as RAW
- use manual focus
- use manual exposure settings (full opening and max shutter time)
- set the ISO manually. Maybe 1 or 2 steps below maximum.
- set it off with the self-timer

The exposure time usually has a maximum of 30 or 60 seconds. When the picture is too bright, use a shorter time.

Do take a lot of pictures with longer/shorter times and higher/lower ISO.

Comment: Thanks, Thats what i was after. Now to find a tripod in Norway!

Comment: [Can be provided for:](http://www.visittromso.no/en/Booking_summer/Winter/Northern-Lights-Chase/) "Included: Aurora chasing, free portrait, photo workshop, photo guide, hot meal, hot drinks, warm winter suit, boots, tripod, transport, crampons, head lamp, hand & foot warmers, and possibility to rent a camera. 
Duration: 8-10 hours"

Comment: OTOH, it seems the folks who chase the northern lights prefer fast lenses. The 12-42 can do it, but [a 12/2 would be better](https://www.flickr.com/photos/norsman1968/12938566534/), and you'd get a wider view with [a Samyang/Rokinon 7.5 fisheye](http://www.mu-43.com/showthread.php?t=16458&page=66&p=413213#post413213).